# Audio input via HTML5?

Tags: html

We have a VoIP application [imVOX](http://imvox.com), and we are looking at various ways of expanding our reach. Part of that is writing an HTML5 application, but it requires the use of audio input from the browser (and also push to talk buttons from the browser, even if another app is focused).

On the audio side, with HTML5 is there any way of taking audio input from the browser to compress and send to our servers? I know with Flash such is possible, but we're trying to avoid flash for mobile compatibility and generally looking toward the future.

Comment: Someone else answered this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webcam and Microphone support is not a feature of the [HTML 5 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#New_APIs)

> **New APIs**
>
> In addition to specifying markup,
>   HTML5 specifies scripting application
>   programming interfaces (APIs).
>   Existing document object model (DOM)
>   interfaces are extended and de facto
>   features documented. There are also
>   new APIs, such as:
>
> - The canvas element for immediate mode
> - 2D drawing Timed media playback
> - Offline storage database (offline web
> - applications) Document editing
> - Drag-and-drop Cross-document
> - messaging (web messaging) Browser
> - history management MIME type and
> - protocol handler registration.
> - Microdata
>
> Some of the new features are part of
>   HTML5 mainly because there are no
>   volunteers to split HTML5 and maintain
>   separate specifications of these
>   features.

Comment: An interesting development on this front. An experimental build of Firefox shows off audio manipulation capabilities. Obviously not viable at the moment, but it reminded me of this question when I saw it :-) http://news.slashdot.org/story/10/05/26/1936224/Breakthroughs-In-HTML-Audio-Via-Manipulation-With-JavaScript?from=rss&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Slashdot%2Fslashdot+%28Slashdot%29&utm_content=Google+Feedfetcher