# Audio capturing with HTML5

Tags: html, audio-recording

I've tried to see if there's a way to record audio
with HTML5 to no avail. I tried using  [this example](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers) 
but it didn't work. I'm guessing he really meant it when he said
that it is not supported by any browser yet.

Am I missing something? perhaps it is already possible?
What are my options to record audio on a browser-based application?

Open Source only please :)

Comment: Until HTML5 catches up, here is an open-source solution for Flash-enabled browsers: https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/ This does not require a Flash media-server back-end.

Comment: Hey Asaf, its about 15 months since you posted this question. Did you ever find an answer? I'm still looking for one.

Comment: This may be worth reading on the emerging standard: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: it seems that the new chrome beta version is implementing some kind of a solution for a microphone and webcam element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might wanna have a look at [HTML Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) and [its API](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-capture-api/).

Ericsson labs already achieved this, see: [here](https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers) (Note: Note that the device element and the related APIs are not available in any browser yet, and the APIs may change before this happens.) But it gives you a rough idea about how it's done.

I am currently working on something like this myself, see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220672/implementing-webbased-real-time-video-chat-using-html5-websockets).

Comment: is this still the case? "Note that the device element and the related APIs are not available in any browser yet"

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution within iOS 6 that I've found so far:

[Youtube video showing how it works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8-HZbWMtEQ)

The source can be found here:
[GitHub Repository Link](https://github.com/rioleo/safari-audiorecord-io6)

It uses an workaround by using iOS6's camera plugin's record features to record video and audio and uploads that to the server. Then FFMPEG crunches the video and extracts the audio as a .wav file.

With all the limitations and unfinalized HTML 5 specs, I think this is the only way for it to work. I hope this helps.