# How to record voice from chromium extension

Tags: html, audio, camera, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Audio capturing with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5)

I'm trying to record voice in my chrome extension.
Is there any API to record user voice. Not flash! only JS html5 etc ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5

Comment: this is definitely not an exact duplicate as it's not limited to html5 (for which there is no current solution, so you effectively closed this question to point him to a dead-end), rather could use other solutions for chrome extensions--NPAPI, speechInput API I don't know. Now I need another question to find out.