# How to record audio in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, audio-recording

What's the simplest way to setup a chrome extension to record audio from the microphone?

- I see there is a working [experimental speech input API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.speechInput.html) but how come you don't have access to the recorded file? Seems like hooking up into that should be simple enough, as it's a step earlier in the process, no? Especially as there is also a text-to-speech API, so you could effectively record into text and then have the computer speak it back out, but unless you want a standard voice, how lame, redundant and prone to error is that?
- Then there seem to be [flash solutions like this](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) but how can I use that in a chrome extension without having to setup anything server-side? (since I don't actually need to send anything to a server--it's all local and client-side)
- Is NPAPI a possibility? Is there such a plugin ready-made?

Don't know of other possible alternatives ([HTML5 isn't ready yet, it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5)) but I welcome anything functional and simple to implement and hook into a chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally a native solution appeared: [Introducing getUserMedia](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/07/introducing-getusermedia-and-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the speech input API, since it will record only the microphone. Okay, you can grab the speakers like that, but it's clearly not the solution. 
Using a NPAPI plugin is a solution. You'll can identify the sound made by a particular tab and after record that source, but it is no longer web dev.

Comment: What do you mean? Recording only the microphone would be good enough for my needs, how could I 'grab the speakers' like that?