# Capturing Audio Through A Website Compatible with Multiple Architectures

Tags: microphone, audio-capture

I was wondering what if any audio capture (through a mic) API's were available that could be integrated into a web server and would be accessible by the majority of Windows, Mac OS X, and mobile phone users. If not, could anyone suggest ways of making audio capture universally accessible without having to rewrite the majority of the code for each platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HTML5 will sort your problem. Assuming the platform has a modern web browser than this solution should work just fine. [Audio capturing with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5)

**NOTE** I have never used this solution but it would seem to do what you want.

Comment: I have looked at HTML 5 Media Capture as a solution but so far, it is only compatible on Android and I think only partially supported on Firefox and IE. If I don't find any other solutions, I will probably stick with HTML 5.