# How to record audio or video in a browser and store it in my server's database?

Tags: php

I need to record audio from a user and store it in my local server's database. I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST[submit1]))
{
echo exec("ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse  -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -vpre      lossless_ultrafast -threads 0  -y  ./Desktop/myVOICE1.wav");
}
?>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="sample.php">

<input type="Text"  name="username">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="go">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

May i know wats wrong wit my code and why doesnt it work?

What should I do?

Comment: this might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227313/audio-capturing-with-html5

Answer (score 1):

You can try the open source ([Red 5](http://osflash.org/red5) ) it uses server side software to capture and distribute.

We tried this, installing it was very frustrated task so I just used Flash Media Server http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/ hosted by another company.

Comment: I agree with the frustration of installing Red5... ;) its a pain in the ***